# Indian Passport and currently in NZ on a tourist visa. I want to visit Australia

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, australia, tourist-visas, new-zealand

I have an Indian Passport and I'm currently in NZ on a tourist visa. I want to visit Australia. Do I have to apply from India or is possible to apply for a visa from NZ?

Comment: What do you mean by "living in NZ on a tourist visa"? "Living in" a place implies that you've made it your permanent home, which isn't possible on a tourist visa.

Comment: "Living in XXX on a tourist visa" is called, hmmm, illegal immigration, no? Or at least borderline.

Comment: @dda not really - I'm living in NZ currently on a 6 month visitor visa, my wife has a 5 month work visa and is currently applying for a 3 year work visa.  When that is received, I can apply for a work visa.  NZ Immigration said they had absolutely and utterly no problems with this approach at all, so long as I didn't exceed my 6 month stay either by leaving the country at the appropriate time or by receiving a visa with a longer duration during my stay.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I would disagree with that, because you can get visas with suitably long durations that certainly put you in the position of having to "live" rather than just "visit" or "stay".  I'm on a 6 month visitor visa (Indian passport holders can get a visitor visa valid for up to 9 months) and I have an NZ bank account, a couch, a TV, internet connection and a house rental for the duration.  I am *definitely* living here right now.  With enough money, you can certainly "live" in NZ without working.

Comment: Poor english aside in the original version, how is this question unclear?  An Indian passport holder currently in New Zealand wants to know if they have to apply for an Australian visa from India or can they apply for it while in New Zealand.  Seems clear enough to me...

Comment: @Moo It's unclear because, in many cases, only residents of a country can apply for visas at embassies in that country. It could very well have been the answer would be "yes" if "living in NZ" meant a situation like yours, and  "no" if it meant that they were on holiday for a few weeks and wondering if they could apply there, rather than waiting until they go home.

Comment: @DavidRicherby and yet Indian passport holders can apply for an Australian visa online, they don't have to attend an embassy or consulate, which means that this persons status in NZ is not important. The timescales involved might indeed be problematic,but that's something that could be worked into an answer as a proviso - it's not grounds for being "unclear" imho. My visa application resulted in a visa in a few hours.

Comment: @Moo I didn't know that when I made my initial comment. That's why my reply to you said that it "could have" made a difference, rather than that it "makes a difference". The question is only clear to people who know what the answer is. However, since I know now what the answer is, I've retracted my close vote.

Comment: @DavidRicherby sorry, not meaning to pick on you, and while I disagreed with your initial comment I didn't have an *issue* with it because it had the potential to expand information via challenges.  My main issue is with the VTC as being unclear, as the question was still legible despite poor English. Imho the question was quite clear, it just needed answering.

Comment: @DavıdRicherby I thnink my comment was rude so I have removed it. And I'm sorry

Comment: @HankyPanky No worries. I just read it as "I think you're wrong" written tersely because it's a comment with a 600-character limit.

Comment: Your NZ visa may only be good for one visit. You should check the conditions and if necessary apply to change them before you leave.
[Reposted as a comment after feedback from @RedBaron.]

Answer (score 4):

According to [Visitor e600 Visa Online Applications](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/600-/Visitor-e600-visa-online-applications), citizens of India are eligible to apply online for a visitor visa:

> If you are outside Australia, you must hold a passport from an eligible country to apply online for a Visitor visa (subclass 600).

Australia lets you apply for a visa from anywhere, it appears. Having an online application makes the process easier than having to visit a consulate.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out explicitly that this means you don't have to be in your own country, as some backward countries allow you to apply in various ways but require you to be in your own country when making the application.